# Multivariate t Distribution and Univariate t Distribution

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, t-distribution

I am wondering about the relation between the univariate and multivariate t-distribution. How is the product of univariate t-distributions with respect to $x_i$ related to the multivariate t-distribution with respect to $X$ and what is the difference between the independent ($x_i$ iid $\forall i$) and dependent case?

Or is there no relation? (Since I wound no publication dealing with these situations)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288738/are-the-marginals-of-the-multivariate-t-distribution-univariate-student-t-distri for information that gives part of the answer to this