# Resulting univariate marginal distributions are not $t$ distributed - why? (S Wood Core Statistics)

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, t-distribution, marginal-distribution

In the Core Statistics by Simon Wood it says:
"If we replace the random variables $Z_i\sim_\text{i.i.d.} N(0,1)$ with random variables $T_i \sim_\text{i.i.d.} t_k$ in the definition of a multivariate normal, we obtain a vector with a multivariate $t_k(\mu, \Sigma)$ distribution. ... Note that the resulting univariate marginal distributions are **not** $t$ distributed.

Could you please explain why not?

It looks like this question [Are the marginals of the multivariate t distribution univariate Student t distributions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288738/are-the-marginals-of-the-multivariate-t-distribution-univariate-student-t-distri) gives different answer.

The way Wood generates MVN is like this:  "Definition Consider a set of n i.i.d. standard normal random variables: Zi ∼ N(0,1). The covariance matrix for Z is In and E(Z) = 0. Let B i.i.d be an m × n matrix of fixed finite real coefficients and μ be an m- vector of fixed finite real coefficients. The m-vector X = BZ + μ is said to have a multivariate normal distribution. E(X) = μ and the covariance matrix of X is just Σ = BBT. The short way of writing X’s distribution is
X ∼ N(μ,Σ)."

Comment: There are *many* ways to define the MVN distribution and they lead to different answers.  Please tell us what definition Wood is using.

Comment: +1.  NB: the problem is that linear combinations of t-distributions generally are not t-distributed.

Comment: so what I don't understand: we start with t-distributed r.v. to get to multivariate t-distribution, yet the marginals are not t-distributed...?

Comment: The marginals, by construction, are linear combinations of t-distributions.

Comment: of course - we're talking about the m-vector X=BT+mu that has multivariate t-distribution, the T_i have t-distribution, but the actual m-vector X does not have t-distribution. Thank you!